# How to convert links to text using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to think up function which can replace links to text. Image inside a tag should be moved to the wrapper, the original a should be removed.

**JS:**

```
var selectors = 'a.mark-video;a.sp5;a>img[alt!=""]'
selectors = selectors.split(";").join(", ");

$(selectors).each(function() {
    var current = this;
    if (this.nodeName == "IMG") {
      current = this.parentNode;
      if (current.nodeName != "A")
        current = this.parentNode;
      if (current.nodeName != "A")
        return false;
      current = $(current);
    }
    var wrapper = current.parent();
    var new_context = $().append(current.html());
    current.remove();
    wrapper.append(new_context);
  }
);
```

The problem is 
1) that the image is not inserted into the wrapper
2) if it would be inserted it would not have correct position.

I am experimenting using webextensions API (Firefox addon) and I injected the code to site: 
http://zpravy.idnes.cz/zahranicni.aspx

In the debugger you can see two wrappers with class="art ". I have removed the first link but image is not inserted. The second one has not been removed yet when debugger was paused after first iteraction.

[image]

I hope you can find out why the image is not appended and how to append it to the original position of the element `a`. I need to find out position of the element `a` first, and then to move the image into to correct position - that is before div.art-info.

Note: please do not change the selectors string. This is the users input from form field.

**Edit:**

Almost there:

```
function(){
   if (this.parentNode.nodeName == "A")
    $(this.parentNode).replaceWith($(this));
   else
    $(this).html().replaceWith($(this)); // error: html() result does not have replaceWith...
  }
```

Comment: In your highlighted code, is the goal to take the link in that anchor tag and turn it into an image using an `<img src="[anchor href here]">`

Comment: No. The image must stay untouched/unchanged. It should make the image unclickable. So you could click on any image without been redirected.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

https://jsfiddle.net/4tmz92to/

```
var images = $('a > img');

$.each(images, function(key, image) {
    $(this).parent().replaceWith(image);
});
```

First select all the images that you want to remove the link from, then loop through them and simply replace the `parent()` with the image.

Comment: Basicly yet, I can change my function to use replaceWith(). It will remove the link and insert the image instead it. Good idea. Thank you.

Comment: How would you solve it in the case that I search for $("a").html() and want to replace the link `a` to innertext? The html() result does not have replaceWith.

Comment: instead of `$(this).html().replaceWith()` it would just be `$(this).replaceWith()`. You don't need both `.html()` *and* `.replaceWith()`

Answer (score 0):

I have finally solved the problem:

```
$(selectors).each(
function(){
   if (this.parentNode.nodeName == "A")
    $(this.parentNode).replaceWith($(this));
   else
    $(this).replaceWith(
      $(this).html()
      );
  }
);
```

This works similar. Novocaine suggested not to use $(this).html() but this would skip some images so I prefer to use it.